# Integral transform for finding what polynomial solves a differential equation.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

If the following kind of differential equations:
$$
\frac{d^2f}{d^2t} + \frac{df}{dt} + f = 0 \\
$$
Have a solution made up by a linear combination of exponentials; which can be easily find by using the laplace transform:
$$
\mathcal L\{ f(t) \} = \int_{0}^{\infty} { f(t) e^{-st} dt} \\
$$
I was wondering if, assuming the solution of the following differential equation:
$$
t^2\frac{d^2f}{d^2t} + t\frac{df}{dt} + f = 0
$$
Is a linear combinations of terms like:
$$
f(t) = A t^r
$$
Could be silly to define a transform like this:
$$
J\{ f(t) \} \equiv \int_{0}^{\infty} { f(t) \; t^{s} dt} \\
$$
My problem is:
$$
J\{ tf'(t) \} = \int_{0}^{\infty} { f'(t) \; t^{s + 1} dt} = t^{s + 1} f(t)\Bigg |_{t = 0}^{\infty} - (s + 1) \int_{0}^{\infty} f(t) \; t^{s} dt
$$
This integral do not converge, so I cannot find the solution of the equation. Is is possible to assume that:
$$
\lim_{t \to \infty} t^{s + 1} f(t) = 0
$$
It is possible to apply this transform, or it is a non-sense? I was expecting something like (take this as an example):
$$
\hat{f}(s) = \frac{s^2 f''(0) + s f'(0)}{s^2 - s + 1} 
$$
And last but not least, how would I find the inverse transform?

Comment: Perhaps you are looking for the [Mellin transform](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mellin_transform).

Comment: The Mellin transform is the idea you have in mind. More generally, you've effectively stumbled upon Sturm-Liouville theory: associated to second order differential equations are integral operators that diagonalize them.

Comment: Can someone explain me quickly how to solve this equation using the transform. How to plug the initial conditons of the differential equation and do the inverse. And how the $t^{s + 1} f(t)\Bigg |_{t = 0}^{\infty}$term